# how to know Orderitem trigger is triggerred by order trigger

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

some fields on orderitem can only be changed when the order is changed, so I need orderitem trigger to know if it's triggered by order trigger. how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is using a static variable. In your Util or other similar class, define a static variable called inOrderTrigger.

```
public static inOrderTrigger = false;
```

Then in your order trigger, set it to be true.

Then in your orderitem trigger, you can check the value of that static variable.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. if I change the value to true in my order trigger. how long does it stays true? for the whole transaction or forever?

Comment: @Lee It stays true in your execution context: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_basics_dotnet/execution_context. Basically, you can understand it as it only stays true for current transaction

Comment: do I need to reset it back to false at the end of the order item trigger?

Comment: @Lee normally don't. It really depends on your requirement.

Comment: @Lee the order trigger should set it back to false to handle cases like recursion, mass updates, etc. Basically: isOrderTrigger = true; update lineItems; isOrderTrigger = false;

Comment: @sfdcfox I don't quite understand this. Are you talking about the scenario when Order trigger calls OrderItem trigger and then calls back to Order trigger? I guess this recursion should be prevented already or by other mechanism?

Comment: @sfdcfox it makes sense, but is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @LanceShi actually I only want it to be true for part of the transaction, any recursion updates will still follow the rule. so I think fox's suggestion is the correct, however is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @Lee there might be, but this is how I do it, and it works well enough.